# how i can realize filtering by value from url in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I did not get to realize filtering through the value obtained in the url
Filter:

```
$scope.categoryFilter = function (products){

                if ($routeParams.categorySlug == products.category.seo_name){
                    return;
                }else {
                    return $scope.products;
                }
            };
```

Routes:

```
when('/products/category/:categorySlug', {
            controller: 'ProductsListController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            templateUrl: '/static/templates/products/products_index.html'
        }).otherwise('/');
```

Json :

```
{
    "name": "pants Classic Pyjama",
    "category": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Белье",
        "description": "",
        "visible": true,
        "products_count": 0,
        "products_count_cache": 0,
        "category_id_name": "2",
        "seo_name": "bele",
        "seo_title": "",
        "seo_desc": "",
        "seo_keywords": "",
        "lft": 2,
        "rght": 5,
        "tree_id": 3,
        "level": 1,
        "parent": {},
    "id": 920
```

In template i use it like these:

```
 <div class="catalog-item" ng-repeat="product in products |filter: categoryFilter">
        <div class="item-pre-title">
            Бесплатная доставка $150+
        </div>
        <div class="item-img">
            <a href="/products/{{ product.id }}/"><img ng-src="{{ product.picture[0].external_img_url }}" width="150px"
                                                       height="150px" alt=""></a>
        </div>
        <a href="/products/{{ product.id }}/" class="item-title">{{ product.name }}</a>
        <div class="item-price">
            <div class="price-old">{{ product.old_price }}</div>
            <b>{{ product.price }}</b>
        </div>
        <div class="item-footer">
            <a href="#" class="item-view"></a>
            <div class="item-sales-alert">
                Получить скиду
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Warning in console:

> angular.js:11706 TypeError: Cannot read property 'seo_name' of null

Help me to resolve it pls :)

> UPD I resolve TypeErro, but filtering still does not work

Comment: Where are you using `categoryFilter` ?

Comment: @kabaehr look at template, i edit it

Comment: Post data for `products`.

Comment: @dfsq i get it from server, in question i posted 1 product from Json with products

Comment: Your code works, can't reproduce the error. Try to create a failing demo, otherwise I can only suggest to add one more check `products.category && $routeParams.categorySlug == products.category.seo_name`

Comment: @dfsq Thanks for trying, bro, i resolve it  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve this problem adding this code instead my old Filter:

```
 $scope.categoryFilter = function (products){

                try {
                    if ($routeParams.categorySlug){
                       if ($routeParams.categorySlug == products.category.seo_name)
                            return products;
                    }else{
                        return $scope.products;
                    }
                }
                catch (TypeError) {
                   return;
                }};
```